# Implementing kernel alignment for SVM algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I am trying to understand and re-implement the results from Table 2 in the first [Kernel-Target Alignment paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2001/file/1f71e393b3809197ed66df836fe833e5-Paper.pdf). The task that is being done is a simple classification task using an SVM with RBF kernels that are aligned using a kernel alignment technique. Is there a tutorial or even a python package that can implement an SVM along with the RBF kernel alignment?

And as an additional question, it seems like kernel-target alignment was (one of) the first kernel alignment techniques. Is it still used today? And what are the general state-of-the art kernel alignment techniques and are there tutorials and packages to implement those?